# SFDX: Authorize an Org failed to run

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, cli

11:55:18.338 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
(node:8748) Warning: Deprecated environment variable: SFDX_JSON_TO_STDOUT. Please use SF_JSON_TO_STDOUT instead.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Warning: The "force auth web login" command has been deprecated. Use "org login web" instead.
Warning: The "--setalias" flag has been deprecated. Use "--alias | -a" instead.
Warning: The "--instanceurl" flag has been deprecated. Use "--instance-url | -r" instead.
Warning: The "--setdefaultusername" flag has been deprecated. Use "--set-default | -s" instead.
Error (1): spawn UNKNOWN
11:55:21.214 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
ended with exit code 1

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting your question. As it is written it's hard for us to help you though, as simply posting the error message you've received doesn't provide any context. What have you tried, how you've replicated this, what version of the SFDX CLI you're using, etc. are helpful to assist you. Please try editing your question and adding some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently experiencing this. I did an sfdx update and then reauthed my org.

```
$ sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias my-super-awesome-alias --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
```

Then `sfdx force:org:open` started working again.